# PRAW Limit number of comments

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am making a program which fetches comments from a specific submission on Reddit. I need to limit a number of comments which I get in order to optimize program. Here is the only solution which PRAW documentation provides; however, obviously it does not make program faster, just allows to operate later with smaller number of comments.

```
def get_comments(reddit: reddit, submission_id: str, limit:int = 10) -> list:
    submission = reddit.submission(id=submission_id)
    #get rid of MoreComments class in submission
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
    submission.comment_sort = "top"
    comments = submission.comments.list()
    return comments[:limit]
```

I suppose, it should be a solution to limit the number of comments directly in request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `limit`.

```
def get_comments(reddit: reddit, submission_id: str, limit:int = 10) -> list:
    submission = reddit.submission(id=submission_id)
    submission.comment_sort = "top"
    comments = submission.comments.list(limit=limit)
    return comments
```

alternative

```
 def get_comments(reddit: reddit, submission_id: str, limit:int = 10) -> list:
    submission = reddit.submission(id=submission_id)
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
    submission.comment_sort = "top"
    comments = submission.comments.list(limit=limit)
    return comments
```

Comment: Unfortunately,  submission.comments.list(limit=limit) does not have attribute limit(

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution in Reddit post. Hope it will help somebody.

```
def get_comments(reddit: reddit, submission_id: str, limit:int = 10) -> list:
    submission = reddit.submission(id=submission_id)
    submission.comment_limit = limit
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)
    submission.comment_sort = "top"
    comments = submission.comments.list()
    return comments
```

Submission has attribute comment_limit, so you can assign value to it. **Make sure you put it before submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0); otherwise it would not work.**